# XSLT 1.0 - How to only copy elements with values, or descendents with values

Tags: xslt-1.0

With XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <Sku />
        <Suppliers>
            <Supplier>
                <Name />
            </Supplier>
        </Suppliers>
        <Priority>1</Priority>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Sku>123</Sku>
        <Suppliers>            
            <Supplier>Jon</Supplier>
        </Suppliers>
        <Priority>3</Priority>
        <e />
    </Product>
</Products>
```

How to transform and only output if element has value, or descendent has a value?
(The 2nd 'filter template' filters empty, with match=***[not(node() )]** , but only if no descendents)

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- When matching empty: do nothing -->        
    <xsl:template match="*[not(node())]">
        <xsl:comment>filtering <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Current output:** (With debug-comments to identify names of filtered elements)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Products>
    <Product>
        <!--filtering Sku-->
        <Suppliers>
            <Supplier>
                <!--filtering Name-->
            </Supplier>
        </Suppliers>
        <Priority>1</Priority>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Sku>123</Sku>
        <Suppliers>            
            <Supplier>Jon</Supplier>
        </Suppliers>
        <Priority>3</Priority>
        <!--filtering e-->
    </Product>
</Products>
```

**Required output:** (without comments)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Products>
    <Product>
        <Priority>1</Priority>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Sku>123</Sku>
        <Suppliers>            
            <Supplier>Jon</Supplier>
        </Suppliers>
        <Priority>3</Priority>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Assume this requires a type of forward-look (recursive template?), to see if any descendents have a value, *before* copying element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "value" you mean a [non whitespace-only](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#strip) [text node](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-Text-Nodes), you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- prune branches that do not carry fruit -->
<xsl:template match="*[not(descendant::text())]"/> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: so simple! Thanks Michael! 